# Can shoutcast be embedded inside a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, helper

Is it possible to include a shoutcast service (an audio broadcast service) inside an application built by flutter (an application for sports commentators), that is, a live audio broadcast is performed every day?

Need answers .........

Comment: There are many streaming solutions for audio and video.  A few are free in low volume ,but most are commercial of course.

Comment: hi @batul-abdulrahman , welcome to https://stackoverflow.com . please before ask the question read this guideline. Your question is opinion based and you may get fewer responses.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask